# React JS & Axios Render after getting response data

Tags: reactjs, axios

How can I make it so that my components render after getting the data from an `axios` GET request?
I have the following components:

```
class CardPool extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            cardListBacklog: [],
        };
    }

    componentWillMount(){
        axios.get('/cards').then(function(response){
            this.setState({cardListBacklog: response.data});
        }.bind(this));
    }

    render(){

        return(
            <div class="row">
                <Section name="Construction of Component 1 with a huge ass name that wont really fit in the section">
                    <Column columnName="BACKLOG">
                        <CardList id="card-list-1" column="0" cardList={this.state.cardListBacklog}/>
                    </Column>
                </Section>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

and

```
class CardList extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            cardList: [],
            laneID: this.props.column
        }
    }

    componentWillMount(){
        this.setState({
            cardList: this.props.cardList,
        });
    }
render(){
        const {connectDropTarget} = this.props;

        return connectDropTarget(
            <div class={"card-list " + this.addClass()} id={this.props.id}>
                {   
                    this.state.cardList ?
                        this.state.cardList.map((card) => {
                            return <Card key={card.id} state={card} laneID={this.state.laneID}/>
                        })
                        : null
                }
            </div>
        );
}
```

The problem is that the `state`'s `cardListBacklog` passed to the `CardList` is not being updated, and the `cardList` in `CardList` component remains empty. What am I doing wrong? Could it be because I am setting `state` properties using the `props`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not giving a chance to `CardPool` component to re-render when response arrives via `axios` call.

Modify the `render` function of `CardPool` component like the following:

```
return this.state.cardListBacklog.length
        ? <div class="row">
            <Section name="Construction of Component 1 with a huge ass name that wont really fit in the section">
                <Column columnName="BACKLOG">
                    <CardList id="card-list-1" column="0" cardList={this.state.cardListBacklog}/>
                </Column>
            </Section>
          </div>
        : null;
```

[This demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/82yj4vp179) demonstrates the barebone implementation

Comment: This answer is ok, there is one more issue. `CardList` has a list in its `state` based on `props` that I modify using `react-plugin'(`update` feature for `state`). How do I make it so that when the `state` in the `CardPool` changes, the `state` in the `CardList` changes? So far, the last `state` changes only when it mounts. Can I modify `props`? I only perceive them as read only objects.

Comment: You can do the `state` change of `CardList` in its [componentWillReceiveProps](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentwillreceiveprops) lifecycle method.

Answer (score 1):

`componentWillMount` lifecycle function is execute only once and hence, when the cardList is available in the parent after the `axios` request, the child component's `componentWillMount` had already executed and hence its state is not updated. Also its not a good idea to set the state which is directly derivable from props, you should instead pass a handler from the parent that is called from Child

```
class CardPool extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            cardListBacklog: [],
        };
    }

    componentWillMount(){
        axios.get('/cards').then(function(response){
            this.setState({cardListBacklog: response.data});
        }.bind(this));
    }

    removeCard = (card) => {
        //do what you need to update cardListBacklog
     }

    render(){

        return(
            <div class="row">
                <Section name="Construction of Component 1 with a huge ass name that wont really fit in the section">
                    <Column columnName="BACKLOG">
                        <CardList id="card-list-1" column="0" cardList={this.state.cardListBacklog} removeCard={this.removeCard}/>
                    </Column>
                </Section>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

and

```
class CardList extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            cardList: [],
            laneID: this.props.column
        }
    }

    render(){
        const {connectDropTarget} = this.props;

        return connectDropTarget(
            <div class={"card-list " + this.addClass()} id={this.props.id}>
                {   
                        this.props.cardList.map((card) => {
                            return <Card key={card.id} state={card} removeCard={() => this.props.removeCard(card)} laneID={this.state.laneID}/>
                        })
                        : null
                }
            </div>
        );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to pass data from parent to children after an axios request in this way:

**Parent Component**

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        peoples: []
    };
}

componentDidMount() {
    axios.get(`https://swapi.co/api/people`).then(res => {
        const peoples = res.data.results;
        this.setState({ peoples });
    });
}
render() {
    const { peoples } = this.state;
    return (
        <div>
            <Header />
            <Main peoples={peoples} />
            <Footer />
        </div>
    );
}
```

**Child Component**

```
export default class Main extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        peoples: []
    };
}
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    const { peoples } = this.props;

    if (peoples !== prevProps.peoples) {
        this.setState({ peoples });
    }
}

render() {
    const { peoples } = this.state;
    return (
        <div>
            {peoples
                ? peoples.map(people => {
                      return <div>people.name</div>;
                  })
                : null}
        </div>
    );
}
```

The problem is that axios request is asynchronous and is possible to data be only received after the child component be mounted. So we need to check if response is received with react hook componentDidUpdate and compare the first value with the new value received to let render print properly.

https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate

Comment: Welcome to SO! When you post an answer, try to explain your P.O.V., as there are more answers, not just paste the code, even if right.